405 Method not allowed During WebSocket Handshake
I've been struggling with this issue for the last 48 hours now. I'm trying to configure websocket in my Spring boot application . I need to publish some messages to a topic which my Angular frontend will subscribe to for refreshing data on the frontend.
This is my WebSocketConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/balle")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");  
    }

}




I was getting 403 earlier as I have a firebase security filter. Now, for testing I  changed to very linient security so this is my security filter chain now.
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {



    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}

I have created a sample html client for testing that connects and subscribes. This is only for testing, ideally i need to connect with my angular project.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebSocket Test</title>
    <!-- Include SockJS from a CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include stomp.js from a CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/stompjs/lib/stomp.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>WebSocket Test Page</h1>
    <button onclick="connect()">Connect WebSocket</button>
    <button onclick="disconnect()" disabled>Disconnect WebSocket</button>

    <script>
        var stompClient = null;

        function connect() {
            // Ensure that this URL matches the endpoint configured on your server
          var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8083/balle');  // Use your WebSocket endpoint here
            stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

            stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
                setConnected(true);
                console.log('Connected: ' + frame);

                stompClient.subscribe('/topic/newAmenityOrder', function (message) {
                    alert("Received: " + message.body);
                });
            }, function (error) {
                setConnected(false);
                console.error('STOMP error: ' + error);
                alert('STOMP error: ' + error);
            });
        }

        function disconnect() {
            if (stompClient !== null) {
                stompClient.disconnect();
            }
            setConnected(false);
            console.log("Disconnected");
        }

        function setConnected(connected) {
            document.querySelector('button[onclick="connect()"]').disabled = connected;
            document.querySelector('button[onclick="disconnect()"]').disabled = !connected;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>

whenever i try to connect i get 405, these are the error logs :
2024-04-17 13:00:39.356 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /balle/info?t=1713339039299
2024-04-17 13:00:39.358 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-17 13:00:39.359 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorized filter invocation [GET /balle/info?t=1713339039299] with attributes [permitAll]
2024-04-17 13:00:39.359 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /balle/info?t=1713339039299
2024-04-17 13:00:39.360 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/balle/info?t=1713339039299", parameters={masked}
2024-04-17 13:00:39.361 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]
2024-04-17 13:00:39.361 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2024-04-17 13:00:39.362 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error?t=1713339039299
2024-04-17 13:00:39.362 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-04-17 13:00:39.363 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorized filter invocation [GET /error?t=1713339039299] with attributes [permitAll]
2024-04-17 13:00:39.363 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error?t=1713339039299
2024-04-17 13:00:39.363 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?t=1713339039299", parameters={masked}
2024-04-17 13:00:39.363 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-04-17 13:00:39.364 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]
2024-04-17 13:00:39.364 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [{timestamp=Wed Apr 17 13:00:39 IST 2024, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, path=/balle/info}]
2024-04-17 13:00:39.365 [http-nio-8083-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405

This is my current CORS :
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*") // TODO IMP - security vulnerability
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}


I already tried creating a Clean slate spring boot application and the same configuration works there perfectly, with the same html file,There I'm able to both Connect and subscribe and receive messages in that clean spring boot application. But here in the main project it doesn't work , so I know there is something in this main project that is causing this. I've tried everything I could so please help, Ask for any other classes If I missed.
I tried connecting to websocket and expected it to connect and subscribe
